# Receive UDP packets to bound client address

Tags: c, udp, ip, client-server, bind

## Overview

Writing a client-server application that communicates using HTTP over UDP in C on Linux for a comp.sci. University project.

The network setup is tricky: both the client and the server need to have their local IP addresses bound. When the client tries to bind the IP address, the server is able to determine the client's IP address, but cannot receive any packets. When the client does not perform a bind, the client and server communicate nearly flawlessly, but the server cannot determine the IP address of the client.

## Client + Server Code

Here is the client code for binding:

**EDIT: moved perror up under the function call as suggested **

```
   if (bind(client_socket.sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(client_socket.client_addr), 
      sizeof(client_socket.client_addr)) < 0){
    perror("error on binding!"); 
    debug(("client: bind"),__LINE__, __FILE__);
    close(client_socket.sockfd);
    return -1;
  }
```

Here is the client and server code for opening a socket:

```
int RDP_getSock(char *server_addr, char *server_port, rdp_socket *rsocket){
  rsocket->sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  if(rsocket->sockfd <0 ){
    return -1;
  }

  bzero(&(rsocket->server_addr),sizeof(rsocket->server_addr));
  rsocket->server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  rsocket->server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(server_port));

  if(server_addr != NULL){
    rsocket->server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_addr);

    if( rsocket->server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr <0 ){
      return -1;
    }

  }

  rsocket->connected = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

The client calls it:

```
  if(RDP_getSock(argv[3], argv[4], &client_socket) <0 ){
        perror("client: error on RDP_getSock()");
        return -1;
    }
```

The server calls it:

```
  if(RDP_getSock( NULL, argv[2], &server_socket) == -1 ){
        perror("server: error on RDP_getSock()");
        return -1;
    }
```

When the client tries to send to the server the following error message appears:

```
receive ACK error: Resource temporarily unavailable
EAGAIN error
: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The code to read from the server (similar to the code to read from the client):

```
ssize_t RDP_receive_from_server(rdp_socket *rsocket, rdp_packet *packet){
  socklen_t address_length = sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );
  bzero(&(rsocket->server_addr), address_length);
  bzero(packet->header.type, RDP_HEADER_TYPE_SIZE);


  return recvfrom(rsocket->sockfd, packet, MAX_PACKET_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&(rsocket->server_addr), &address_length);
}
```

There are timeouts set on both the client and the server. But since the client and the server are, technically, on the same machine, I cannot understand why forcing the client to bind to the local IP address is failing.

The code that actually sends the packet (to/from the client/server):

```
ssize_t RDP_send_packet(rdp_socket *rsocket, rdp_packet *packet, int to_client){
  ssize_t result = -1;
  socklen_t address_length = sizeof( struct sockaddr_in );
  char src_ip[256];
  char dest_ip[256];
  bzero(src_ip, 256);
  bzero(dest_ip,256);

  if(to_client){
    debug(("send to client"),__LINE__, __FILE__);
    result = sendto(rsocket->sockfd, packet, sizeof(struct RDP_packet), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&(rsocket->client_addr),sizeof(rsocket->client_addr));

    // inet_ntoa(rsocket.client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(server_socket.client_addr.sin_port));

    strncpy(src_ip, inet_ntoa(rsocket->server_addr.sin_addr), 256);
    debug(src_ip,__LINE__, __FILE__);

    strncpy(dest_ip, inet_ntoa(rsocket->client_addr.sin_addr), 256);
    debug(dest_ip,__LINE__, __FILE__);

    RDP_logline(
      's',
      src_ip,
      ntohs(rsocket->server_addr.sin_port),
      dest_ip,
      ntohs(rsocket->client_addr.sin_port),
      packet->header.type,
      packet->header.seq );     
  }
  else{
    debug(("send to server"),__LINE__, __FILE__);
    result = sendto(rsocket->sockfd, packet, sizeof(struct RDP_packet), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *)&(rsocket->server_addr),sizeof(rsocket->server_addr));  

    strncpy(src_ip, inet_ntoa(rsocket->client_addr.sin_addr), 256);
    debug(src_ip,__LINE__, __FILE__);

    strncpy(dest_ip, inet_ntoa(rsocket->server_addr.sin_addr), 256);
    debug(dest_ip,__LINE__, __FILE__);

    RDP_logline(
      's',
      src_ip,
      ntohs(rsocket->client_addr.sin_port),
      dest_ip,
      ntohs(rsocket->server_addr.sin_port),
      packet->header.type,
      packet->header.seq );        
  }

  debug(("send complete"),__LINE__, __FILE__);
  return result;
}
```

## Logging Showing IP Addresses

Here is a log line from the client, showing the client IP/port and server IP/port, with binding on the client (the IP address 192.168.1.100 is the expected value):

```
2013-08-06 18:47:27.433176 s 192.168.1.100:8080 10.10.1.100:9090 SYN 1
```

From the server side:

```
2013-08-06 18:52:30.321409 s 0.0.0.0:9090 0.0.0.0:0 ACK 1
```

Log lines from the client, showing the client IP/port and server IP/port, with no binding:

```
2013-08-06 19:22:17.613885 s 176.39.64.0:0 10.10.1.100:9090 ACK 2
```

From the server:

```
2013-08-06 19:22:17.613858 s 0.0.0.0:9090 10.10.1.100:37887 FIN 2
```

The IP address and port seemingly assigned to the client is random (e.g, 176.39.64.0:0) when bind is not used on the client side.

## Question

Any ideas why bind'ing on the client is preventing the server from sending back the ACK packets?

Comment: You need to call perror() *immediately* after a system call that fails, not several function calls later. Otherwise the value of errno may have been disturbed and you will print the wrong error message.

Comment: I modified and ran it and there is still no error on the bind function call, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: UDP doesn't send to IP addresses, it sends to MultiCast Groups (they look like IPs but are in the range `224.0.0.0` to `239.255.255.255`). I'm not familiar enough with your code to identify whether this is your issue, but it works as an answer for a large proportion of UDP questions.

Comment: @Robadob Nonsense. UDP is used for both unicasting and multicasting, and indeed broadcasting as well. And a multicast address *is* an IP address.

Comment: Do not mix IP and UDP up, they are separated protocols. Actually, Robadob is right by saying: "UDP does not send to IP addresses" (but the rest of his comment is wrong). UDP itself sends data to a port. Have a look at the UDP header definition and you will not find any IP addresses but source and destination port. The IP address is used to find the correct host, the port to find the correct (UDP) application.